# Fluxo alternativo em Fluxo Alternativo de Caso de Uso pode?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml

Eu gostaria de saber se eu posso ter um fluxo alternativo dentro de um fluxo alternativo em um use case. Tipo o fluxo alternativo A1 que tem o A2:

```
A1: O usuário clicou em Excluir
1 - O sistema solicita aprovação
2 - O usuário confirma (A2) (Aqui tem o alternativo do usuário clicar em "não" )
3 - O sistema exclui 
4 - O sistema imprime a mensagem "excluído com sucesso"

A2. O usuário clicou em Não
1 - O sistema retorna ao fluxo principal.
```

Isso esta certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, não há problemas ter um fluxo alternativo dentro de outro fluxo alternativo.

A forma como o UC é descrito, depende da cultura da empresa. Por exemplo eu descrevi desta forma em meu TCC, a professora aprovou. Entretanto, quando apliquei na minha anterior empresa, utilizei da seguinte forma:

A1: O usuário clicou em Excluir
1 - O sistema solicita aprovação;
2 - O usuário confirma;
    2.1 - Caso o usuário clique em não, o sistema retorna para o fluxo onde foi chamado;
3 - O sistema exclui;
4 - O sistema imprime a mensagem "excluído com sucesso".

Na empresa que estou agora, estamos descrevendo da mesma forma que você, um fluxo alternativo para a confirmação da exclusão.